# Is setIdFieldName dangerous for db objects?

Tags: database, object

Varien_Objects and their descendents provide a way to refer to objects by `id`s by another name.

```
/**                                  
 * set name of object id field       
 *                                   
 * @param   string $name             
 * @return  Varien_Object            
 */                                  
public function setIdFieldName($name)
{                                    
    $this->_idFieldName = $name;     
    return $this;                    
}
```

There is no issue here for unbound objects, but when interacting with the database, there's the fear that changing the apparent id of an item will create SQL errors at save time. And indeed, there is a chance of that happening. In Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract:

```
/**
 * Save object object data ()
 *
 * @param Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object
 * @return Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
 */
public function save(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object)
{
    …
    if (various_conditions) {
        $condition = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->quoteInto($this->getIdFieldName().'=?', $object->getId());
        $this->_getWriteAdapter()->update($this->getMainTable(), $data, $condition);
…
```

So the field used to find the item to save is altered by changing the idFieldName. As long as that field is unique and not null (and preferably indexed), you're fine. But nothing that I can see particularly guarantees that the idFieldName an arbitrary programmer chooses will meet those criteria. So it's up to the individual programmer to manually validate idFieldName before setting it, or risk broken writes to the database on save. Is that analysis correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, there aren't any checks enforced on the `fieldname` you are setting. Basically you could add just about any field, also one that isn't unique.

It does have an advantage in a way that it gives you the ability to update multiple rows if you wish, although there are probably better ways to do so